# Why does the output of cout << *lkop[4] is a 0?

Tags: c++

So, i wrote this code:

```
int arr[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
 int (*lkop)[10] = &arr;
 cout << *lkop[4];
```

I was expecting an int 4 to show up, but the output is a 0;
Why is that happening, iam really confused.Any ideas?
Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator.

`lkop[4]` is out-of-range because `arr`, which `lkop` points, has only one element of `int[10]`.

To do dereferencing first, you should add parenthesis: `cout << (*lkop)[4];`.

Comment: Thank you so much,  really appreciate it.

Comment: Mike: [please check out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407291/).  Help vampire?